# Unable to validate conditionally with zod validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zod

I have a form that has a radio button, that has three input fields inside it. And i have a submit button that will validate that only one of the input fields are correctly entered. I used refine() in zod validation but nothing happens. it always validate the three inputs, what is the problem here?

```
export const FormSchema = z.object({
  firstname: z.string().min(1, {message:"Please enter a name."}),
  address: z.string().min(1, {message:"Please enter an address."}),
  email: z.string().min(1, {message:"Please enter an email."}),
}).refine(
    data => data.firstname || data.address || data.email,
    "Either first or second or third should be filled in."
  );;

export type FormSchemaType = z.infer<typeof FormSchema>;
```

```
const [searchOption, setSearchOption] = useState("searchName");

<FormProvider {...methods}>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)} noValidate>
   <RadioButton id="1" value="searchName"/>
   <InputField
     type="text"
     name="firstname"
     label="First Name"
   />
   <InputField
     type="text" 
     name="address"
     label="Address Name"
   />
   <InputField
     type="email" 
     name="email"
     label="E-mail"
   />      
 </form>
</FormProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the `min` function from all the fields validation and have this object:

```
  const FormSchema = z
    .object({
     firstname: z.string(),
     address: z.string(),
     email: z.string()
  })
```

Because the `min` function tells you that the fields must have at least one character.